# Opening folder with Remote-Container fails due to PowerShell being used to execute Dockerfile build steps

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, remote-access, vscode-remote

I was hoping to test out the new Remote Development extension using the Remote-Containers functionality. I grabbed the [sample Python](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-try-python) project and opened it using the `Remote-Containers: Open Folder in Container...` function.

[image: Remote-Containers: Open Folder in Container]

The initialisation process kicks off fine, stepping through some of the Docker build without problem. Steps 1-3 in the Dockerfile succeed and then step 4 (lines [13/14](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-try-python/blob/master/.devcontainer/Dockerfile#L13-L14) of the Dockerfile) throws an exception and exits because the `RUN` command includes an `AND_IF` operator (`&&`). This is because it's being passed as a subcommand to PowerShell which doesn't support `&&`.

I've followed the [instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) for preparing my system for using the Remote-Containers functionality, including adding both my drives (C: and D:) to the Shared Drives.

Troubleshooting I've tried so far:

- switching between Linux and Windows containers
- swapping between PowerShell, Git Bash, and WSL (Ubuntu) as the default shell for Visual Code (`terminal.integrated.shell.windows`)
- using one of the other Remote-Container examples from Microsoft
- creating a very basic project with one simple Python file and attempting the `Remote-Containers: Open Folder in Container...` again, selecting `python:3` as the targeted Docker image

None of the above steps have produced any different outcomes.

Docker Inspect reveals that the `Config`->`Shell` setting is:

```
"Shell":
  [
    "powershell",
    "-Command",
    "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"
  ]
```

while the `Config`->`Cmd` setting is:

```
"Cmd":
  [
    "powershell",
    "-Command",
    "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';",
    "apt-get update     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils 2>&1"
  ]
```

The full container config is [here](https://pastebin.com/x6NHEu5y).

The reason for the exception is obvious but I can't discern why the Dockerfile `RUN` instruction is being passed to PowerShell like above.

I'm running Visual Studio Code - Insiders (1.36.0-insider) and Docker Engine 18.09.2 on Windows 10 (1809).

The exception produces the following error when step 4 fails (I've included the preceding successful steps for context; flattened the pip install in step 2 for brevity):

```sh
Setting up container for folder: d:\Development\vscode-remote-try-python-master
Run: docker build -f d:\Development\vscode-remote-try-python-master\.devcontainer\Dockerfile -t vsc-vscode-remote-try-python-master-486294f4d73f25a657ec08f53ff07d5f d:\Development\vscode-remote-try-python-master
Sending build context to Docker daemon  24.06kB
Step 1/13 : FROM python:3
 ---> 22a423a5db36
Step 2/13 : RUN pip install pylint
 ---> Running in 23380af29dd1
Successfully installed astroid-2.2.5 colorama-0.4.1 isort-4.3.20 lazy-object-proxy-1.4.1 mccabe-0.6.1 pylint-2.3.1 six-1.12.0 typed-ast-1.4.0 wrapt-1.11.1
Removing intermediate container 23380af29dd1
 ---> 5569fa48c9c5
Step 3/13 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 ---> Running in 941086f674cb
Removing intermediate container 941086f674cb
 ---> b8b2fd47bdb1
Step 4/13 : RUN apt-get update     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils 2>&1
 ---> Running in defcc073adcf
At line:1 char:91
+ ... ; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; apt-get update && apt-get ...
+                                                                ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; apt-get update     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils 2>&1' returned a non-zero code: 1
Failed: Building an image from the Dockerfile.
Command failed: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe build -f d:\Development\vscode-remote-try-python-master\.devcontainer\Dockerfile -t vsc-vscode-remote-try-python-master-486294f4d73f25a657ec08f53ff07d5f d:\Development\vscode-remote-try-python-master
```

Is this a common experience for anyone else? Would appreciate any solutions or suggestions for troubleshooting further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seemingly results from the use of Windows Containers, as discussed in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/876).

> Yeah, unfortunately Windows Containers are not supported and using LCOW in "Windows Containers mode" for Docker Desktop is not something we really support right now given its experimental state.
>
> LCOW still has gaps like supporting single file bind mounting that can cause issues and things like PostgreSQL are called out as not working yet. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers#work-in-progress) and [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33850).
>
> The [Windows recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers#when-to-use-moby-vm-vs-lcow) right now is primarily to use LCOW on an exception basis:
>
> > ### When to use Moby VM
> >
> > Right now, we recommend the Moby VM method of running Linux containers to people who:
> >
> > - Want a stable container environment. This is the Docker for Windows default.
> > - Run Windows or Linux containers, but rarely both at the same time.
> > - Have complicated or custom networking requirements between Linux containers.
> > - Don't need kernel isolation (Hyper-V isolation) between Linux containers.
> >
> > ### When to use LCOW
> >
> > Right now, we recommend LCOW to people who:
> >
> > - Want to test our newest technology.
> > - Run Windows and Linux containers at the same time.
> > - Need kernel isolation (Hyper-V isolation) between Linux containers.